# In an express app deployed with Zeit Now, is there a way to view server-side console logs?

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

In my `index.js`, the file that imports express and handles routing, I have a `console.log('Hi mom')` statement. How can I view that output after deploying with `$ now` or `$ now dev`?

`$ now logs` shows me output that is different from the output I would see in my terminal after running `$ yarn start`. Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Real-time request logs should be available in the "functions" tab under [deploy-url.now.sh/_src](http://deploy-url.now.sh/_src) after you use "now".

[image]

Comment: So Now doesn't let you see stdout??

Comment: It does. The platform simply doesn't retain logs. It will stream directly to your browser once you have the "functions" tabs open.

Comment: Well but this is just request info. I was looking for the Node.js output that I see in my terminal when I enter something like `$ yarn start`. For example "Listening on port 3000!" Maybe it has something to do with the Now runtime mapping everything from an express app to a serverless function ...  or however that works.

Comment: That is not possible. Now is a serverless environment so it will never listen to a port.